# ConcurrentModificationException in Play for Scala + Hibernate

Tags: scala, hibernate, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have two Hibernate classes in Play/Scala, `Group` and `Item`, where one Group may have many Items. What I need is to remove all the items from a group. I try to remove like this:

```
val group = session.get(classOf[Group],groupCode)
val it = group.items.iterator
while(it.hasNext) {
   val i = it.next
   group.items.remove(i)
}
```

The first iteration works fine, but on the second iteration I get `ConcurrentModificationException`.

What is this exception and how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove element from list, which you are currently iterating use

```
it.remove()
```

It removes from the underlying collection the last element returned by this iterator.

If you are interested in reasons why ConcurrentModificationException gets thrown here if you modify the list directly you can take a look at this javadoc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html

> Note that this exception does not always indicate that an object has been concurrently modified by a different thread. If a single thread issues a sequence of method invocations that violates the contract of an object, the object may throw this exception. For example, if a thread modifies a collection directly while it is iterating over the collection with a fail-fast iterator, the iterator will throw this exception.

Comment: `it.remove` works, however when I save the parent object I get an SQL exception thrown by Hibernate. In the SQL log I see that it tries to update the items table instead of deleting the rows. Since it tries to set a column with null, JDBC throws the error. This is the log entry: `update items set group_sk=null where group_sk=?`. Why it tries to update instead of delete?

Comment: Removing item from group.items list removes only connection between item and group - it doesn't delete Item object itself. If you want to delete Item object you need to do session.delete(i)